# Dynamically give list items <li> a unique class with PHP

Tags: php, class, dynamic

I am dynamically populating a list based on what is in the database, and I would like each list item to have a unique class name - something simple, for example the first

would have the class item-1, and the second

would have the class item-2. 
This is the php code I am using to create the list:

```
 <?php
          $metas=trim(get_post_meta($post->ID,'hike_meta',true),'');
          $metas_arr=explode("\n",$metas);
          $metas1=array_slice($metas_arr,0,3);
          $metas2=array_slice($metas_arr,3,3);
?>

<div class="loca_meta">
    <ul>
       <?php foreach($metas1 as $meta){
             list($k, $v) = explode('|', $meta);
             echo "<li><span class='bold'>$k</span>:<br>$v</li>";
          }?>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="loca_meta">
        <ul>
          <?php foreach($metas2 as $meta){
                list($k, $v) = explode('|', $meta);
                 echo "<li><span class='bold'>$k</span>:<br>$v</li>";
           }?>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

What extra code do I need, to give each list item a unique class? As a side note, I am very much a beginner when it comes to php, so please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `$counter` variable to get the incremented value and assign it to class.

```
<div class="loca_meta">
    <ul>
       <?php $counter = 0; foreach($metas1 as $meta){
             list($k, $v) = explode('|', $meta);
             echo "<li><span class='bold <?php echo "item_".$counter ?>'>$k</span>:<br>$v</li>";
          $counter++;
        }?>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="loca_meta">
        <ul>
          <?php foreach($metas2 as $meta){
                list($k, $v) = explode('|', $meta);
                 echo "<li><span class='bold <?php echo "item_".$counter ?>'>$k</span>:<br>$v</li>";
           $counter++;
          }?>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` loop:

```php
   <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($metas1); $i++){
         list($k, $v) = explode('|', $metas[$i]);
         echo "<li><span class="bold item-".$i+1.">$k</span>:<br>$v</li>";
      }?>
```

Result will be:

```html
<li><span class="bold item-1"><!-- content --></span>:<br><!-- content --></li>
<li><span class="bold item-2"><!-- content --></span>:<br><!-- content --></li>
<li><span class="bold item-3"><!-- content --></span>:<br><!-- content --></li>
```

and so on.

Comment: As you have now started `$i` at 1, this may miss `$metas[0]` out.